# Currency getting differently formatted on iOS and android with same locale

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, locale, currency-formatting

I am working on an application using React Native where I need to show currency in Euro and in rupees as well.

I am using Javascript's [Intl](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/NumberFormat#Syntax) for formatting the currency as per the locale using `en-IN` for rupees and `en-GB` for euro.

but the currency is shown with different formatting on iOS and in android, in iOS the currency is showing correctly for IN like `3,74,73,474` but the same is shown on android with this format: `37,473,474`. Not sure how do I approach for this. Below is the utility function I wrote for formatting:

```
getformattedCurrency(value) {
   const formatter = new Intl.NumberFormat('en-IN', {
      style: 'currency',
      currency: 'INR'
      minimumFractionDigits: 0,
      maximumFractionDigits: 0,
   });
   return formatter.format(value);
}
```

I know that android's native have [DecimalFormat](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/DecimalFormat) to do this but I want to achieve this via JS only.

Any help is appreciated ! Thanks.

Comment: Can you provide an example number that you trying to convert and results that you get, those ### not giving enough information on result. Also you may try it without minimum and maximum fraction digits parameters. If you want have rounded number you can do that math before converting.

Comment: @maximelian1986 I have edited the question to provide real data. Please have a look at it.

Comment: Did you debuged it? Do you getting different values from that method or you see different values on your app ui? May be something after that method render result number in that strange form? And does your initial number is 37473.474 ?

Comment: Yes i have debugged and then only came to the conclusion that the method is returning different values and the initial number is `37473474` not `37473.474`

Comment: I still testing but now I noticed that you have typo, you missing comma before minimumFractionDigits param...may be that is in your code as well if you copy/paste it here.

Comment: I have done that typo while taking the snippet here and reformatting it. Thats not in the real code. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like for some reason it is unable to select which script from Intl library to use.
So

```
import 'intl';
import 'intl/locale-data/jsonp/en-IN';
import 'intl/locale-data/jsonp/en';
```

When you import en-IN separatly it works on android. Unable test on iPhone.

Comment: Or may be it is expected behavior and you need to import each currency separately.

Comment: Okay thanks. I will check this and will confirm ! Thanks :)

Comment: this works in both platforms. Sorry to revert late. Thanks again !

Comment: where should I import this?

Comment: I am getting error saying intl could not be found within the project